# SSRS 2016 : Issue using custom Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, reporting, ssrs-2016

I have a problem using a custom set of parameters.

I have data coming back in raw format. Some are numbers and some are `.011` for percent.

I also have a format table that reviews the data and set it to the correct display based upon format. I have added two custom parameters, `Target Min` and `Target Max`. these parameters are text parameters and based upon what you enter, they change the color of the background for the table.

For example, if the `Target Min` is 35 and `Target Max` if 45, the text boxes with 35-45 are colored yellow and if they are above 45 they are colored red.

The problem comes in when I am adding the Min and Max for a percent. The raw data is `.11` but the display based on Format is 11%. The parameters are not picking up the values unless I add `.11` for Min and whatever for Max.

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just divide you parameter value by 100 when you evaluate it in your expressions. That way the Parameter can read 11 and the actual values can remain at 0.11

Comment: I tried adding logic to the parameter that states if the format is percent, divide by 100, else nothing. It blew up.

Comment: I'm not following now, can you post your report design including any relevant expressions, output from your dataset and sample parameter values.

Comment: The data looks like: (DashboardID, MetricID, MetricName, OrgUnit, TimePeriod, DataThroughDate, FormatString, Value, etc.). For metrics that have a format string of "0.0%" the value comes out as a decimal ".11". I have create two parameters that are text.

Comment: One called TargetMin and the other TargetMax. If a value is between Target Min and Target Max the cell color is yellow. If it is above TargetMax, it is Red. The problem comes in when you select a metric that is percent and set the value for the TargetMin or Max to 11 instead of ".11". When I try and put in an expression for The default or available values based upon the formatstring filed, I get an error stating I cannot add a field to the parameters expression.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, can update your question with sample output from your datasets, Also show details of your parameters (type, values, defaults, datasets to populate them if any, etc, etc). I'm sure this is fairly simple to resolve but as I can't see what you are looking at I don't want to spend time suggesting a solution to a problem I've misunderstood.

Comment: Alan, Thank you for your help. I have resolved the issue by creating a new query and using it as a dataset for the parameters and they are working great. I was hoping to not have to create a new query, but alas, I had to to get this report completed.